# Can a secondary domain point to an existing nameserver and be redirected?

Tags: dns, nameservers, amazon-route53

I have a client that has two domains.
ex:
**domain1.net.br** and **domain2.net**.

domain1.net.br is already registered in my aws route53 and has 4 nameservers assigned to it.

I told my client that he should use the same nameservers for **domain2.net** to make it redirect.

I tought this would work but It didn't.

Shouldn't any domain having the nameservers be able to redirect to another domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I told my client that he should use the same nameservers for domain2.net to make it redirect.
>   I tought this would work but It didn't.

You are correct, this will not work.  Route 53 assigned unique name servers for each of your domains.

> Shouldn't any domain having the nameservers be able to redirect to another domain?

HTTP redirects are not a function of a name server, but of a web server.  The easiest way to redirect domain2.net to domain1.net.br is to create an Amazon S3 bucket and utilize the [Web Page Redirects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) feature.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i'll dig in to it!